# List of Tables and total columns and count of primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to list the all tables and each tables count columns and each table count of (primary+foreign key) used in my DB

EG: table 1 contain 2 columns and one primary key then result should be like below

```
Tables List         Total columns    Primary+foreign Key count
1                   2                1
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Also - what does Table List = 1 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT C.TABLE_NAME,
       Count(C.COLUMN_NAME)  AS TOTAL,
       Count (A.COLUMN_NAME) AS [PRIMARY+FORIGN KEY COUNT]
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TC.TABLE_NAME,
                                        COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
                               INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU
                                       ON KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                                          AND KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                          AND KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                          AND KCU.TABLE_NAME = TC.TABLE_NAME
                        WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN( 'PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY' )) A
                    ON C.TABLE_NAME = A.TABLE_NAME
                       AND C.COLUMN_NAME = A.COLUMN_NAME
GROUP  BY C.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of [Information Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms186778.aspx)

```
-- All info
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

--Count Info
SELECT 
table_name,count(column_name) ColCount,count(constraint_name) ConstraintCount
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
group by table_name

--Seperate Count Info
SELECT 
a.table_name,count(a.column_name) ColCount,count(a.constraint_name) ConstraintCount,
(SELECT 
count(b.constraint_name) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE b where b.constraint_name like 'PK%'
AND b.table_name = a.table_name
group by table_name ) PKCount,
(SELECT 
count(b.constraint_name) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE b where b.constraint_name like 'FK%'
AND b.table_name = a.table_name
group by table_name ) FKCount

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE a
group by a.table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select name,
        count_columns = (select COUNT(*) from syscolumns where id = S.ID),
        count_FK_PK = (select COUNT(*) from sysobjects where (xtype = 'F' OR xtype = 'PK') AND parent_obj = S.id)
from sysobjects S
where xtype='U'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below one

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.NAME) TABLECOUNT, COUNT(C.NAME) COLUMNCOUNT, SUM(CASE WHEN T.TYPE LIKE 'PK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PRIMARYCOUNT,
SUM(CASE WHEN T.TYPE = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FORIEGNCOUNT
 FROM SYS.OBJECTS T LEFT JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C
ON T.OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.NAME) TABLECOUNT, COUNT(C.NAME) COLUMNCOUNT, 
(SUM(CASE WHEN T.TYPE LIKE 'PK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
SUM(CASE WHEN T.TYPE = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))  'PK+FK'
 FROM SYS.OBJECTS T LEFT JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C
ON T.OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select q1.TABLE_NAME,q2.cnt,q1.pkandfk from (select scr.TABLE_NAME, sum(scr.pkandfk) as pkandfk from (select itc.TABLE_NAME,case 
when itc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE in ('FOREIGN KEY','PRIMARY KEY') then 1
else 0 
end  as pkandfk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS itc
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ikcu 
on ikcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=itc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) scr
group by scr.TABLE_NAME)
q1 join (select TABLE_NAME,count(column_name)as cnt from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS group by table_name) q2
on q1.TABLE_NAME=q2.TABLE_NAME
```